# regarding MSB, in representing negative decimal to binary equivalent in c++

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

I am trying to represent negative Decimal NO. into Binary

and My code works as designed, but I am unsure if my design achieves my goal."

but i have doubt regarding MSB

i know for negative Decimal  numbers the MSB is kept 1 in binary form

so what i did for representing 2's complement of a number i kept MSB 0 as currently i am showing 2's complement of positive number

but for representing  same 2's complement as binary representation of negative decimal Number

i changed MSB to 1

here's the Output:

```
binary representation of 8 is 1000
full binary representation of 8 is 00000000000000000000000000001000
1's complement of  8 is 11111111111111111111111111110111
2's complement of  8 is 01111111111111111111111111111000

as negative decimal numbers are basically stored as 2's complement of postive decimal equivalent 
Full  binary representation of -8 is 11111111111111111111111111111000

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

i wanted to know if printing 2's complement of positive number is equal to binary represention of negative number??
so my approach is right or wrong???
AND here's the code if required

```
//!!!!this code is not working in my vscode but woeking on online compilers
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

void DeciToBin(int a)
{
    int b=a;
    int sum=0;
    int bit,q=0;

    if(a>0)                                            
    {                                                    
        //binary of 12 is   1100                        
        while(a!=0)
        {
            bit= a&1;

            sum= ( bit * pow(10,q) ) + sum;
            //cout<<pow(10,q)*bit<<endl;
            
        // cout<<sum<<endl;
            a= a >>1;
            //cout<<a<<endl;
            q++;
        }
    }
   
    else
    {
       
       int e=-a;
       int arr[32];  //since integer cant store 32 bit length to representation binary we will operate on array
       int count=0;

       while(e!=0)
        {
            bit= e&1;

            sum= ( bit * pow(10,q) ) + sum;
            //cout<<pow(10,q)*bit<<endl;
            count++;
            e= e >>1;
            q++;
        }
        
       cout<<"binary representation of "<< (-a) <<" is "<<sum<<endl;  
       
       
        int sum2=sum;
        for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=0;
        }
        
       for (int i = 31; i >=32-count; i--)    //storing everybit in array (normal representation of decimal number in binay)
       {
            arr[i]= sum2%10;
            sum2=sum2/10;
       }
       
       
       cout<<"full binary representation of "<< (-a) <<" is ";  
       for(int i=0;i<32;i++)         //output if decimal number is 6 :  00000000000000000000000000000110 
            cout<<arr[i];
       
       
      //1's complement
      for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
      {
          if(arr[i]==1)
                arr[i]=0;
          else
                arr[i]=1;
      }
      
       cout<<"\n1's complement of  "<< (-a) <<" is ";  
       for(int i=0;i<32;i++)        
            cout<<arr[i];
        
        
        /* convert back to its original binary form, so that we can apply trick to calculate 2's complement
        which works directly on original bibary form of a decimal number */
        for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
        {
          if(arr[i]==1)
                arr[i]=0;
          else
                arr[i]=1;
        }
   
            
        //2's complement by using trick on GFG ** this trick works directly on binary of number not on 1s complement
        for( int i=31 ; i>0 ; i-- )
        {
            if(arr[i]==1)   //check from LSB if the bit is 1 or not , if 1 then turn rest bits in 1(if 0) or in 0(if 1)
            {               // ex  number is 0110100 then it will 1001000 is a 2's complement
            
                for(int j = i-1 ; j>0 ; j--)    // keep j>0 if number is positve and j>=0 if number is negative
                {                                   // as MSB defines if number is negative or +ve ,its for representation only
                    if( arr[j] == 0 )
                        arr[j] = 1;
                }
            break;
            }   
        }
    
        cout<<"\n2's complement of  "<< (-a) <<" is ";  
        for(int i=0 ; i<32 ; i++ )        
            cout<<arr[i];
            
        
        cout<<endl<<endl<<"as negative decimal numbers are basically stored as 2's complement of postive decimal equivalent ";    
        
        arr[0]=1;   //since number is negative i am changing MSB to 1
        cout<<endl<<"Full  binary representation of "<<a<<" is ";
        for(int i=0;i<32;i++)        
            cout<<arr[i];
        
    }   //end of else
    //cout<<"binary Form of "<<b << " is "<<sum<<endl;
}
int main()
{   
    //system("cls");
    int a=-8;
    DeciToBin(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How/why did you change the MSB from `1` to `0` when going from 1s complement to 2s complement?

Comment: Unrelated but please don't use the floating-point `pow` for integer powers. I recommend you create your own function to handle integer powers instead.

Comment: @AdrianMole actually i didnt calculate 2's complement from 1's complement 
i used trick to calculate 2's complement directly from original binary form

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes many suggested me to not use pow 
i intend to write my own power function later

Comment: Your two's complement of 8 is wrong, the MSB should be `1`.

Comment: @john No. The 2's complement of 8 is `0000....0001000`. For non-negative values inside the range of both signed 2's complement and unsigned versions of the representation the binary representations are simply the same.

Comment: @sujalsharma You do know that you can implement this properly with much less code? https://godbolt.org/z/vqxazhseM

Comment: *"I am trying to represent negative Decimal NO. into Binary"* -- No, you are trying to represent a negative **number** in binary. While the `-8` in your code is in decimal, that representation does not exist after compilation. The compiler will convert the character sequence `-8` to whatever format is required by `int`, and that format is what your function receives. If you really want to deal with a decimal representation (which I think is not the case), you'll need to take the input as a string.

Comment: @fabian Agreed, I didn't express myself well. I think it's pretty clear from the context that what is meant is to take the binary representation of 8, and then two's complement that value. The two's complement of -8 in other words.

Comment: @john ohh that i intentionally didnt changed MSB to 1 
now i realise it was stupid of me to do that

Comment: @JaMiT i was asking about the approach and was bit confused regarding MSB's in negative numbers 
i wanted to know  if printing 2's complement of positive number is equal to binary represention of negative number??

Comment: @JaMiT post updated
,
english is not my first language so i had difficulty to express what i really want to ask 
thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @sujalsharma OK, I think I get what you meant. I have a new suggestion. Please consider changing *"and my code working fine"* to *"My code works as designed, but I am unsure if my design achieves my goal."*

Answer (score 1):

The output of your program is incorrect even ignoring the fact that the output 2's complement representation is incorrect:

The representation of `8` in 1's or 2's complement matches the original binary. You're attempting to print the negated representations here, i.e. bit sequences representing `-8`.

Furthermore I don't know where you got that trick of negating a 2's complement number from, but it's either wrong or incorrectly implemented.

Here's an approach I'd consider simpler:

1. Swap all bits.
2. Treat the bit sequence as unsigned integer and add 1 taking the resulting value modulo `2^n`, i.e. simply drop the carry after you've got the same number of bits the original had.

```
{
    // Negating a number in 2's complement (which the original value is in) can be done by negating every bit and then
    // adding 1 as if the number was unsigned and ignoring overflow

    int carry = 1; // we're swapping bits and adding 1 at the same time
    for (size_t i = 32; i != 0;)
    {
        --i; // delay the decrement, since the loop variable is unsigned
        auto val = (1 - arr[i]) + carry;
        if (val == 2)
        {
            val = 0;
            carry = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            carry = 0;
        }
        arr[i] = val;
    }
}
```

Note that there's functionality in the standard library that simplifies this greatly.

```
#include <bit>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void PrintBinary(int32_t valueDecimal, T value, char const* representation)
{
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << valueDecimal << " is " << std::bitset<32>(std::bit_cast<uint32_t>(value)) << " in " << representation << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    constexpr uint32_t value = 8;
    constexpr int32_t negatedValue = -value;

    PrintBinary(value, value, "binary");
    PrintBinary(negatedValue, ~value, "1's complement representation");
    PrintBinary(negatedValue, negatedValue, "2's complement representation");
}
```